# AWS ECR - How to get last-pull-datetime per repository?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, dockerhub, amazon-ecr

I need to set a Lifecycle policy, and I want to determine the rules by checking last-pull-datetime, per repository.

This feature comes out-of-the-box in DockerHub, is there a way to get this type of information in AWS ECR (Elastic Container Registry)? I've Google a lot about it and haven't found anything.

Here's how it looks like in DockerHub -

[image]

The API call - https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/api/latest/#operation/GetNamespacesRepositoriesImages returns "last_pulled"

[image]